# std::inner_product with omp

Tags: c++, stl, openmp

Is it possible to parallelize `std::inner_product()` from C++ with `omp.h` library? Unfortunately I can't use `__gnu_parallel::inner_product()` available in newer versions of gcc. I know that I can implement my own `inner_product` and parallelize it, but I would like to use standard means.

Comment: You can run two or more concurrent inner products with OpenMP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The whole point of algorithms like `inner_product` is that they abstract the loop away from you. But in order to parallelise the algorithm you need to parallelise that loop – either via `#pragma omp parallel for` or via parallel sections. Both methods are inherently linked to the loop in the code structure so even if the loop were trivially parallelisable (which it might well be), you need to put the OpenMP pragmas *inside* the function to apply parallelism to it.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Hristo's comment, you can kind of do this by decomposing the arrays over threads, calling `inner_product` on each subarray, and then using some sort of reduction operation to combine the sub-results

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <omp.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
void tick(struct timeval *t);
double tock(struct timeval *t);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  const long int nelements=1000000;
  long int *a = new long int[nelements];
  long int *b = new long int[nelements];
  int nthreads;
  long int sum = 0;
  struct timeval t;
  double time;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (long int i=0; i<nelements; i++) {
        a[i] = i+1;
        b[i] = 1;
  }

  tick(&t);
  #pragma omp parallel 
  #pragma omp single
  nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();

  #pragma omp parallel default(none) reduction(+:sum) shared(a,b,nthreads) 
  {
       int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
       int nitems = nelements/nthreads;
       int start = tid*nitems;
       int end   = start + nitems;
       if (tid == nthreads-1) end = nelements;

       sum += std::inner_product( &(a[start]), a+end, &(b[start]), 0L);
  }
  time = tock(&t);

  std::cout << "using omp: sum = " << sum << " time = " << time << std::endl;

  delete [] a;
  delete [] b;



  a = new long int[nelements];
  b = new long int[nelements];
  sum = 0;

  for (long int i=0; i<nelements; i++) {
        a[i] = i+1;
        b[i] = 1;
  }
  tick(&t);
  sum = std::inner_product( a, a+nelements, b, 0L);
  time = tock(&t);

  std::cout << "single threaded: sum = " << sum << " time = " << time << std::endl;

  std::cout << "correct answer: sum = " << (nelements)*(nelements+1)/2 << std::endl ;

  delete [] a;
  delete [] b;

  return 0;
}

void tick(struct timeval *t) {
    gettimeofday(t, NULL);
}

/* returns time in seconds from now to time described by t */
double tock(struct timeval *t) {
    struct timeval now;
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    return (double)(now.tv_sec - t->tv_sec) + ((double)(now.tv_usec - t->tv_usec)/1000000.);
}
```

Running this gets better speedup than I would have expected:

```
$ for NT in 1 2 4 8; do export OMP_NUM_THREADS=${NT}; echo; echo "NTHREADS=${NT}";./inner; done

NTHREADS=1
using omp: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.004675
single threaded: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.004765
correct answer: sum = 500000500000

NTHREADS=2
using omp: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.002317
single threaded: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.004773
correct answer: sum = 500000500000

NTHREADS=4
using omp: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.001205
single threaded: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.004758
correct answer: sum = 500000500000

NTHREADS=8
using omp: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.000617
single threaded: sum = 500000500000 time = 0.004784
correct answer: sum = 500000500000
```

Comment: ...but of course you can write calls to `inner_product` that don't have the property that they decompose nicely like this.

Comment: You can use `omp_get_max_threads()` instead of this trick with `omp_get_num_threads` in a `single` construct, because you might run into the nice OpenMP feature of dynamic teams (given the proper environment) and get `1`.